Magento 2 main.ERROR: Warning: Array to string conversion in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/AbstractModel.php on line 186 [] []
We are using magento 2.4.6-p3 version.
When we clear the cloudflare cache then we are getting this issue on error log files -

Jun  5 08:26:16 abc-ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx Magento[12879]: main.ERROR:
Warning: Array to string conversion in
/var/www/vhosts/abc.ab.xy/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/AbstractModel.php
on line 186 [] []

How we can solve this ?
It is only coming after clear the cloudflare cache.

Could you give more details about the problem?
